# Passing and updating data along node-express app

Tags: node.js, express

How can I pass and update data along node-express app without using DB.

So I am using passport to authenticate (consider this to be in **src/google-passport.js**),

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL:  process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
    userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
    accessType: 'offline'
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) => { 
        let profileSort = extractProfile(profile)
         mongooeHelperFunction.findUserByEmail(profileSort.email).then(response => {
           if (!response) {
            mongooeHelperFunction.createNewUser(profileSort)
            .then(res => {
               let newRes = {...res._doc}
                newRes["accessToken"] = accessToken
                cb(null, newRes)
            })
            .catch(error => {  throw error  })
           } else {
                let newRes = {...response._doc}
                newRes["accessToken"] = accessToken
                cb(null, newRes)
           }
        })
        .catch(error => {  throw error  })
    }
))
```

From Passport, I am getting an **access token and refresh token**. Usually Google access token is valid for an hour.

So I want to store the time when I receive my access token and If my access token is expired, I want to use a refresh token to get a new access token and then update the time after new access token is generated.

consider an api route

```
app.get("/something", isTokenValid, (req, res) => {
```

where `isTokenValid` is a middleware function and inside that function I could have **when** my passport token was created and then i could compare it with current time.

Aditionally if the token have expired, I have a function which would send the refresh token to get new access token and update the previous data/time of access token to the new date/time

**Question:** how can I pass and update data along node-express app

Answer (score 2):

#### Create Context Object

As in your example, we add another middleware that creates context for middleware pipeline:

```
const initCtx = (req,res,next) => {
    req.ctx = {};
    next();
}
```

Then in your middleware declaration:

```
    app.get("/something", [initCtx, isTokenValid], (req, res) => {
```

Generally this could be done as first middleware in the pipeline, at top of your middleware declarations in whole app:

```
const initCtx = (req,res,next) => {
    req.ctx = {};
    next();
}
app.use(initCtx);
```

#### Passing Value into `ctx`

In `isTokenValid` middleware where you retrieving `accessToken`, and its expiration time, at end of it you can pass it through. Where access token expiration is `tokenExpiration`:

req.ctx.tokenExpiration = tokenExpiration;

#### Using value

In middleware that takes care of refreshing tokens :

```
 app.get("/something", [initCtx, isTokenValid], (req, res) => {
       const tokenExpiration = req.ctx.tokenExpiration; // you have token expiration time that you can compare and apply required logic in refreshing token middleware
```

#### Original Reply and Explanation

You can assign  property `ctx` (context object) to express `req` object and pass through it information between middlewares. Then you will be able to check specific keys in this object in downstream middlewares and apply required logic.

`ctx` object could be created by first middlewares in the pipeline (this one often also checks `requestId` from headers and assigns it to `ctx` as well, so all actions within context of same request could be easily traced )

If token is valid you can assign `req.ctx.tokenExpiration`,  and then in another middlewares check if there need to refresh it.

By the way Koa and Loopback frameworks work with ctx object out of the box.

Comment: I can create ctx by simply doing something like this? `res.ctx = date.now` in my express-app?

Comment: Better to create ctx in other, first middleware in pipeline `app.use((req,res,next)=>{req.ctx = {}; next();});` . Also i corrected my answer - better to use `req.ctx`. Then you need in `isTokenValid` middleware to assign: `req.ctx.tokenExpired`. And yes, you just create `ctx` object per request, assign it to request, and then you can populate, check, use properties from it across all middleware pipeline

Comment: firstly! Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you please be add more details to your answer? (like include context from your text). 
For some reason I am unable to comprehend **how to** from your answer

Comment: Thanks and please do it :)

Comment: I did refactor and provided more detailed answer. Hope that helps :)